# Installing Mapserver on Ubuntu?

Tags: mapserver, installation, ubuntu

I followed instructions at http://www.mapserver.org/installation/unix.html
but it didn't work well.

My system is ubuntu 14.04 and I'm a total rookie when it comes to unix/compiling/working with the terminal

**First Question:** *Is there a functioning script which can be executed in the terminal?* ( I don't know c - compiling well and don't know how to get all required packages)

All I did so far is set up the Apache2. When I browse localhost with Firefox, I get the "Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page".

**Second Question:** I want to make a mapserver and a mapclient as WMS-server which is based on geotiff and shapefiles.

*Where can I find information to get things started?*

Comment: I think it should be divided into two separate questions

Answer (score 5):

In order to install the MapServer in Ubuntu 14.04 after you have installed Apache2, it is good to install php5:

`sudo apt-get install php5`

After that you can install the available in the repositories version of the MapServer by executing:

```
sudo apt-get install cgi-mapserver mapserver-bin php5-mapscript
```

However, the available version in the Ubuntu repository is not the latest one. In order to get the latest one you should add the `ubuntugis-unstable` repository and then run the install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
sudo apt-get install cgi-mapserver mapserver-bin php5-mapscript
```

Don't forget to check or set the correct permissions for the `/var/www` directory. You can set the permissions like that:

```
sudo adduser Your_User_Name_Here www-data 
sudo chown Your_User_Name_Here:www-data -R /var/www 
sudo chmod 0755 -R /var/www
```

Now, you just have to enable CGI and restart the Apache2 service:

```
sudo a2enmod cgi && sudo service apache2 restart
```

In order to verify the installation you can check if the MapServer is presented in the `phpinfo()` output:

```
touch /var/www/html/info.php
echo '<?php phpinfo(); ?>' >> info.php
```

Navigate to `http://localhost/info.php` and search for the MapServer row in the table to verify the installation.

For the second question, you can follow the MapServer documentation [WMS Client](http://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_client.html) that is quite complete and sufficient to get you started.

Comment: I get a mistake at "sudo apt-get install cgi-mapserver mapserver-bin php5-mapscript" 

It says: E: Unable to locate package cgi-mapserver-bin. Do I have to download it under Github and save it somewhere?

Comment: @steveomb No, you don't have to download anything. Mapserver is available in the Ubuntu universe packages. You can check your spelling, execute `sudo apt-get update`, ` apt-cache search cgi-mapserver` or `apt-cache policy cgi-mapserver`. If any of this don't give you a clue for the error, open another thread.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time since I last compiled MapServer, but usually all you had to do was:

```
./configure
./make
./make install
```

'configure' basically evaluates what libraries are installed on your machine and creates a 'make file'. 'Make' then compiles the mapserv executable.

To serve shapefiles and tifs I think you need the gdal library, so you may have to install or compile that manually.

It may also be worth to take a look at UbuntuGIS (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGIS), it has packages for mapserver and gdal already that you can just install.